# How to insert initial Data in Spring Many to Many Relationshionsip

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relation in my Spring boot project. By the declaration of the two entities in the project which are mapped together, everything is OK.

However, I want to insert data into the tables when I initially run the application to have some initial data in the tables. I am having problem doing this. This works well when I remove the relationship

Below is how I declare the entities using JPA annotations:

Subscriber Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="subscribers")
public class Subscriber {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long subscriber_id;

@Column(name= "firstname")
@Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Please enter a valid first name")
@NotEmpty(message = "First Name is required.")
public String firstname;

@Column(name= "lastname")
@Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Please enter a valid first name")
@NotEmpty(message = "Last Name is required.")
public String lastname;

private Set<Cluster> clusters;


@Pattern(
        regexp = "^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])$",
        message = "Invalid Email address. Enter Correct Email Address"
)
@Column(name= "emailaddress")
@NotEmpty(message = "Email is required.")
public String email;

public Subscriber()
{
    super();
}

public Subscriber(String firstname, String lastname, String email,       Set<Cluster> clusters)
{
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname =  lastname;
    this.email =     email;

}

public long getSubscriberId()
{
    return subscriber_id;
}

public void setSubscriberId(long subscriber_id)
{
    this.subscriber_id = subscriber_id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname()
{
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname)
{
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail()
{
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email)
{
    this.email = email;
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subscribers")
public Set<Cluster> getClusters()
{
    return clusters;
}

public void setClusters (Set<Cluster> clusters)
{
    this.clusters = clusters;
}
```

Cluster Entity

```
@Entity
public class Cluster {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public long cluster_id;

@Column(name= "clustername")
@NotNull
public String clusterName;

@Column(name= "location")
public String location;

@Column(name= "apiaddress")
public String apiAddress;

@Column(name= "contact")
@NotNull
public String contact;

public Date creationDate;

public Set<Subscriber> subscribers;

public Cluster()
{

}

public Cluster(String clusterName, String location, String apiAddress, String contact, Set<Subscriber> subscribers)
{
    super();
    this.clusterName = clusterName;
    this.location =  location;
    this.apiAddress =     apiAddress;
    this.contact = contact;

}

public long getClusterId()
{
    return cluster_id;
}

public void setClusterId(long cluster_id)
{
    this.cluster_id = cluster_id;
}

public String getClusterName()
{
    return clusterName;
}

public void setClusterName (String clusterName)
{
    this.clusterName = clusterName;
}

public String getLocation()
{
    return location;
}

public void setLocation (String location)
{
    this.location = location;
}

public String getApiAddress()
{
    return apiAddress;
}

public void setApiAddress (String apiAddress)
{
    this.apiAddress = apiAddress;
}

public String getContact()
{
    return contact;
}

public void setContact (String contact)
{
    this.contact = contact;
}

public Date getCreationDate()
{
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate)
{
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="cluster_subscriber", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="cluster_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public Set<Subscriber> getSubscribers()
{
    return subscribers;
}

public void setSubscribers(Set<Subscriber> subscribers)
{
    this.subscribers =subscribers;
}
```

}

Code that is used to Add the data which is the Entry point in the Spring Boot Application and this is where I am getting the Error

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AiAdminApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AiAdminApplication.class, args);
  /*ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AiAdminApplication.class, args);


  String [] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String name: beanNames){
        System.out.println(name);
    }*/
}

@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final SubscriberRepository subscriberRepository;
    private final ClusterRepository clusterRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseLoader(SubscriberRepository subscriberRepository, ClusterRepository clusterRepository) {

        this.subscriberRepository = subscriberRepository;
        this.clusterRepository = clusterRepository;
    }

    public void run (String...strings) throws Exception {
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Olalekan Samuel", "Ogunleye", "olalekan@aithenticate.za.com", 1));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Pieter", "Erasmus", "pieter@aithenticate.za.com", 2));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Nico", "Boss", "nicoboss@aithenticate.za.com", 3));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Felix Parfait", "Tandem", "parfait@aithenticate.za.com", 4));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Nkosinathi", "Nkosinatthi", "nathi@aithenticate.za.com", 5));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Balleng", "Balleng", "balleng@aithenticate.za.com", 6));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Nicolas", "Immelman", "nicolas@aithenticate.za.com", 7));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Nicolo", "Carzavallian", "nicolo@aithenticate.za.com", 8));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Shaun", "chang", "shaun@aithenticate.za.com", 9));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Andre", "Immelman", "ali@aithenticate.za.com", 10));
        this.subscriberRepository.save(new Subscriber("Michel", "Immelman", "michel@aithenticate.za.com", 11));

        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("Aws-eu-west-1", "Ireland", "123.98.45", "Olalekan Samuel", 1));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("Azure", "United State", "123.98.45", "Pieter Erasmus", 1));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("Google Cloud", "United State", "123.98.45", "Nico Boss", 1));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("herekou", "United Kingdom", "123.98.45", "Felix Parfait", 2));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("IBM", "United State", "123.98.45", "Nkosinathi Nkosinathi", 4));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("herekou", "United Kingdom", "123.98.45", "Balleng Immelman", 5));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("Aws-eu-west-1", "Ireland", "123.98.45", "Nicolas Immelman", 6));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("Azure", "United State", "123.98.45", "Nicolo Carzavallian", 6));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("Google Cloud", "United State", "123.98.45", "Shaun Chang", 5));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("herekou", "United Kingdom", "123.98.45", "Andre Immelman", 7));
        this.clusterRepository.save(new Cluster("IBM", "United State", "123.98.45", "Michel Immelman"));


    }
}
```

}

I'm getting a cannot be applied error, but everything is fine if I remove the mappings and the id appended in the end.

Any help on how to insert the data in the entry application will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Constructor expect a Set and you are passing an int parameter that you then proceed to ignore?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me. Can you please tell me which of the constructor expects a Set? Thank you again

Comment: both Cluster and Subscriber... that can't even compile

Answer (score 0):

create a class implementing ApplicationListener and put your code. This class might be called multiple time during Startup depending on your web.xml entries.
SO be cautious while inserting, you may end up in duplicate data.

```
public final class SystemStartUp implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
       //put startup code here
    }
}
```